C# Dynamic Object call TryInvoke with an unknown array of arguments
I need to invoke a given DynamicObject with a given array of arguments. However, I am struggling on how exactly to do this.
What I would like to do:
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Reflection;

InvokeDynamicObject(new A(), ((object[])["asd", 1, null]));

object? InvokeDynamicObject(DynamicObject dyn, object?[] args)
{
    dyn.TryInvoke(/* what? */, args, out object? res);
    return res;
}

class A : DynamicObject
{
    public override bool TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, object?[]? args, out object? result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Called with args {String.Join(", ", (args ?? []).Select(a => a is null ? "null" : a.GetType().Name))}");
        result = null;
        return true;
    }
}

If the arguments were fixed it would be easy ((dynamic)dyn)(arg1, arg2, arg3) but how do I do this for an array of provided args?
I think I need to call TryInvoke using reflection, but what do I provide for the InvokeBinder argument? I didn't find any way to create one, do I need to implement one myself (and what would that need to do?)?

This seems like an odd thing to try to do. DynamicObject is designed for use with fixed code (using the dynamic keyword. Can you share the underlying problem you're trying to solve? It's likely you'll be better off passing some kind of (untyped) object or delegate directly, and use reflection against that object rather than using DynamicObject.

You would need to use some APIs whose documentation say "is not intended to be used directly from your code". This is likely an XY Problem.

@StriplingWarrior I am working with JS as a scripting language (using Jint) and I have a custom Type system. The Type objects get passed to the engine and should be able to be constructed, however, they need to be callable in order to do that. A very intuitive approach to that would be to allow for calling functions on dynamic objects in JS, however, this is currently not supported in Jint and I wanted to add it in my fork. Cannot pass a delegate since this looses the additional info contained in the type object which breaks c# code working with type return values from the engine.

@Sweeper I reckon I should have mentioned more of the special circumstances. Would you mind telling me about those APIs so I myself am able to make a decision on whether or not I need to use them?

You can see what code the C# compiler generates for ((dynamic)dyn)(1,2,3) on sharplab.io and you basically have to reproduce that. Somewhere along the line you'd need a delegate type corresponding to the number of parameters you are passing. This means that you will need to dynamically load new delegate types for more than 15 parameters.

I reckon this would be extremely slow compared to using dynamic in the "normal" way, since you must recreate the call site every time. dynamic simply is not designed for this.

I'm not quite sure I follow. So you've got a ScriptFunction from Jint, and instead of just calling Call(...) you want to... what, exactly?

@StriplingWarrior Its not that easy to explain. I don't have ScriptFunctions, I have type objects (which contain information about the type like constructors, statics, origin, etc.). Types can be defined in JS or CLR, so using standard jint type reg is no use. Used to write only constr to Jint engine, but then no other type info. I thought that callable type objects (using dynamicobj which i already use to resolve statics etc.) would be the easiest way to allow construction while retaining all the type info, but I definetly see I naively underestimated the complexity.

First, you should understand that you could never exactly replicate what a compiler would generate for the same list of arguments. The compiler has access to compile-time type information, which could affect the binding process. With a object?[], you don't have access to that. F("foo") and F((object)"foo") might bind to totally different methods, but your InvokeDynamicObject method cannot distinguish between them. Your method doesn't know the compile time type of the arguments.
Second, I encourage you to check out on SharpLab, how a dynamically bound call is done under the hood.

The compiler creates an array of CSharpArgumentInfos. One for each argument, and an extra one for the object on which you are calling the method.
A CallSiteBinder is created by calling Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.Invoke. This method takes some flags, the type in which this call occurs (for access control purposes), and the argument infos created in step 1
The CallSiteBinder is used to create a CallSite<T>, where T is a delegate type. This will be a different delegate type depending on the types and number of arguments. For example, for the argument list (1,"foo",true), T would be Func<CallSite, object, int, string, bool, object>. The first object is the type of the receiver, and the second object is the return type.
The CallSite is stored in a static field so that it can be reused.
CallSite.Target is invoked with the corresponding parameters.

You'd need to do each of these steps dynamically. The most difficult one is probably 3, since you need to find an appropriate delegate type. Func only goes up to 16 parameters, so for calls with more than 14 arguments, you need to load your own delegate types dynamically!
That aside, here is a basic outline. Be aware that I've used some !s here.
static object? InvokeDynamicObject(DynamicObject dyn, object?[] args)
{
    // step 1
    var argInfos = Enumerable.Repeat(CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null), args.Length + 1).ToArray();

    // here I have used the runtime type of the arguments, and typeof(object) if the argument is null
    var argTypes = args.Select(x => x?.GetType() ?? typeof(object)).ToArray();

    // this creates the T in CallSite<T>
    var callSiteDelegate = Type.GetType($"System.Func`{args.Length + 3}")!.MakeGenericType([typeof(CallSite), typeof(object), ..argTypes, typeof(object)]);

    // steps 2 and 3, assuming this happens in a class called 'Program'
    var callsite = CallSite.Create(callSiteDelegate, Binder.Invoke(CSharpBinderFlags.None, typeof(Program), argInfos));

    // step 5
    var field = typeof(CallSite<>).MakeGenericType(callSiteDelegate).GetField("Target");
    return ((Delegate)field!.GetValue(callsite)!).DynamicInvoke([callsite, dyn, ..args]);
}

This doesn't handle calls of more than 14 arguments, and it doesn't cache the CallSite. You'd need to dynamically create new delegate types to support more than 14 arguments, possibly using things from System.Reflection.Emit. You might want to store the CallSites in a Dictionary<int, CallSite>, one for each arity.

Thank you. I didn't realize the complexity (since from the "over" the hood, there is hardly any code to look at) and understand why you mentioned doing this dynamically post-compile is not a good idea. I am still very happy to have learned a bit more about how the binder works, and the sharplab site is a great tip!

As long as the TryInvoke implementation (like yours) doesn't use it, you can pass null! for the InvokeBinder argument when calling it.
dyn.TryInvoke(null!, args, out object? res);

Overall your code seems fine and prints
Called with args String, Int32, null

when I run it with that one change.
If you wanted to pass extra call-site information or return type information to your dynamic method, you would have to subclass InvokeBinder and construct an instance yourself, but that's optional and mainly used when bridging dynamic languages (JS, Python) to C#, I believe.

Thanks, issue is this needs to work for other (unknown) dynamic implementations and i can't really check whether they use it or not. So i reckon there is no alternative to implementing an invokebinder myself? How does the invokebinder that gets constructed when the dynamic object is called with fixed args get constructed by the runtime?
